Error with an array constant in a TypeScript file
I'm trying to compile the code-paredit package in VS Code. VS Code reports the following error about file src/extension.ts:
Type '[[string, ({ textEditor, ast, selection }: { textEditor: any; ast: any; selection: >any; }) => void], (string | (({ textEditor, ast, selection }: { textEditor: any; ast: any; >selection: any; }) => void))[], (string | (({ textEditor, ast, selection }: { textEditor: any; ast: any; selection: any; }) => void))[], ... 18...' is not assignable to type >'[[string, Function]]'.
  Source has 22 element(s) but target allows only 1.

The error occurs in line 52 of file extension.ts. Here is the code causing the error:
const pareditCommands : [[string, Function]] = [

    // NAVIGATION
    ['paredit.forwardSexp',            navigate(paredit.navigator.forwardSexp)],
    ['paredit.backwardSexp',           navigate(paredit.navigator.backwardSexp)],
    ['paredit.forwardDownSexp',        navigate(paredit.navigator.forwardDownSexp)],
    ['paredit.backwardUpSexp',         navigate(paredit.navigator.backwardUpSexp)],
    ['paredit.sexpRangeExpansion',     navigateRange(paredit.navigator.sexpRangeExpansion)],
    ['paredit.closeList',              navigate(paredit.navigator.closeList)],
    ['paredit.rangeForDefun',          navigate(paredit.navigator.rangeForDefun)],
        
    // EDITING
    ['paredit.slurpSexpForward',       edit(paredit.editor.slurpSexp, {'backward': false})],
    ['paredit.slurpSexpBackward',      edit(paredit.editor.slurpSexp, {'backward': true})],
    ['paredit.barfSexpForward',        edit(paredit.editor.barfSexp, {'backward': false})],
    ['paredit.barfSexpBackward',       edit(paredit.editor.barfSexp, {'backward': true})],
    ['paredit.spliceSexp',             edit(paredit.editor.spliceSexp)],
    ['paredit.splitSexp',              edit(paredit.editor.splitSexp)],
    ['paredit.killSexpForward',        edit(paredit.editor.killSexp, {'backward': false})],
    ['paredit.killSexpBackward',       edit(paredit.editor.killSexp, {'backward': true})],
    ['paredit.spliceSexpKillForward',  edit(paredit.editor.spliceSexpKill, {'backward': false})],
    ['paredit.spliceSexpKillBackward', edit(paredit.editor.spliceSexpKill, {'backward': true})],
    ['paredit.wrapAroundParens',       edit(paredit.editor.wrapAround, '(', ')')],
    ['paredit.wrapAroundSquare',       edit(paredit.editor.wrapAround, '[', ']')],
    ['paredit.wrapAroundCurly',        edit(paredit.editor.wrapAround, '{', '}')],
    ['paredit.indentRange',            indent],
    ['paredit.transpose',              edit(paredit.editor.transpose)]];

What is wrong?

[[string, Function]] defines an array with a single element of type [string, Function]. You want const pareditCommands : [string, Function][] = ... instead
